# android keyboard acts differently on device compared to emulator

Tags: android, keyboard, emulation

When testing an android project on an emulator the keyboard seems to work fine.  However, when I test on my samsung phone the keyboard works incorrectly.  One problem is that when my first display comes up the keyboard automatically appears although it doesn't in an emulator.  Secondly, if I type something and hit the return or enter key, the keyboard won't disappear on my phone.  Is there a separate step needed to dismiss the keyboard?  Thirdly, sometimes when I hit hit the enter key, it causes the cursor to go to a new line rather than submitting the data.  Again, none of this is a problem with the emulator.  So what do I have to do to make the keyboard work correctly on my phone device?

Below is my code for receiving and submitting data with ana AutocompleteText view.

```
   autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.suggest);
        autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String newText = s.toString();
                int len = newText.length();
           //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text changed count = " + String.valueOf(len), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(len > 1)
                    new getData().execute(newText);
            }

        });
```

Sometimes when I hit the enter key, it goes to another line rather than executing my asynchronous task.

Comment: Again please provide some layout codes to get helped besides posting questions serially.

Answer (score 0):

you required to **forcefully open and close** the **soft keyboard** for your requirements.

for **Open** *soft keyboard*:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(your_edit_text, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

for **Close** *soft keyboard*:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(your_edit_text.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

for correct working **done(Enter)** key you should put following *properties* to **Edit Text** in **.XML** file.

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: THanks for the suggestions.  I will add this code and see if it works better.